# How to derive a column based on multiple columns values for a single row

Tags: sql-server

I currently have an issue with a calculation I'm trying to create.

So I have 8 columns, all with the same 3 values:

```
1 = pass   , 2 = borderline  , 3 = Fail.
```

I need to be able to calculate a new column which will state the following:

```
Pass = All 8 fields equals '1'  
Borderline = 7 Fields that equal '1' with one field that equals '2' 
Else Fail
```

It seems a easy calculation but I keep tripping up on the borderline logic, as any of the 8 columns could have the '2'?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your columns will have only 1,2 or 3 then you can try this

```
case Col1 + Col2 + Col3 + Col4 + Col5 + Col6 + Col7 + Col8 When 8 Then 'Pass'
when 9 Then 'Borderline' 
Else 'Fail'
End
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simple calculate the total of the 8 columns, and if the value is greater than 9 it's a fail. This assumes no NULL or 0 values are in the 8 columns.

```
SELECT  Col1 + Col2 + Col3 + Col4 + Col5 + Col6 + Col7 + Col8 AS Total
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple addition with a `CASE` statement to work this out.

Rules:

- 8 passes: total always = 8
- 7 passes and 1 borderline: always = 9
- Any other combination = fail

Sample code:

```
-- dummy table
CREATE TABLE #temp
    (
      c1 INT , c2 INT , c3 INT , c4 INT ,
      c5 INT , c6 INT , c7 INT , c8 INT
    )

-- dummy data    
INSERT  INTO #temp
        ( c1 , c2 , c3 , c4 ,
          c5 , c6 , c7 , c8
        )
SELECT 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1,2,3,1,1,1,1,2

-- query to calculate totals and pass/fail
SELECT  *, 
    CASE t.Total WHEN  8 THEN 'Pass' 
                 WHEN 9 THEN 'Border Line' 
                 ELSE 'Fail' END Overall
FROM    ( SELECT    * ,
                    c1 + c2 + c3 + c4 + c5 + c6
                    + c7 + c8 Total
          FROM      #temp
        ) t
-- clean up
DROP TABLE #temp
```

Produces:

```
c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  c7  c8  Total   Overall
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   8       Pass
1   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   9       Border Line
1   2   3   1   1   1   1   2   12      Fail
```